# gremlin transaction handling using java

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I am using java to connect to JanusGraph using gremlin and using following code to create Vertex and Edge. Currently i am using g.tx().commit() as part of client.submit as shown below code :

```
        try {
        String sessionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Client client = cluster.connect(sessionId);
        client.submit("graph.tx().open()");
        client.submit("g.addV('Person').property('Name', 'Justin').next()");
        **client.submit("graph.tx().commit()");**
        List<Result> rs = client.submit("g.V().count()").all().join();
        System.out.println("Result size is "+rs.size());
        System.out.println(rs.get(0).getString());
        client.closeAsync();

    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

So want to know if there is any other more appropriate way to handle transactions using java or this is the only way to do so.

Thanks,
Atul.

Answer (score 2):

If you are submitting requests to a remote JanusGraph server then that is the way to do it. You use `connect(<sessionId>)` to create a session and then submit scripts against it. In the recently released TinkerPop 3.5.0 however there are changes to that rule. You can now do bytecode based sessions as well as script based sessions which means that the transaction API is now unified for both embedded and remote use cases. You can see more in the 3.5.0 Upgrade Documentation found [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/upgrade/#_transaction_improvements).

The 3.5.0 release is quite recent, having only been announced a couple of weeks ago. As a result at the time of this answer, JanusGraph does not yet support it (though work has started on it [here](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/2619)). Until you are on a release of JanusGraph that supports TinkerPop 3.5.0 you have two options for transactions:

1. The one you are doing for remote use cases or,
2. Use JanusGraph in the [embedded style](https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/transactions/).

For the latter, as taken from the documentation in the link provided:

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("berkeleyje:/tmp/janusgraph")
juno = graph.addVertex() //Automatically opens a new transaction
juno.property("name", "juno")
graph.tx().commit() //Commits transaction
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, i will go ahead with my approach for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean transactionExample() {
        System.out.println("Begin Transaction");
        Transaction tx = g.tx();
        String id = "123321";
        GraphTraversalSource gtx = tx.begin();
        try {
            gtx.addV("T").property(T.id, id).next();
            System.out.println("Searching before commit ==> " + gtx.V().hasId(id).elementMap().next());
            if (2/0 == 0) {
                throw new TransactionException("throwing exception");
            }
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("Committed Transaction");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Catching exception " + ex);
            System.out.println(gtx);
            tx.rollback();
            System.out.println("Rollbacked Transaction");
           
        }
        System.out.println(gtx.tx().isOpen());
        
        return true;
    }
```

For more information refer https://github.com/m-thirumal/gremlin-dsl